# Move only files recursively from multiple directories into one directory with mv

Tags: bash, unix, gnu, directory, mv

I currently have ~40k RAW images that are in a nested directory structure. (Some folders have as many as 100 subfolders filled with files.) I would like to move them all into one master directory, with no subfolders. How could this be accomplished using `mv`? I know the `-r` switch will copy recursively, but this copies folders as well, and I do not wish to have subdirectories in the master folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your photos are in `/path/to/photos/` and its subdirectories, and you want to move then in `/path/to/master/`, and you want to select them by extension `.jpg`, `.JPG`, `.png`, `.PNG`, etc.:

```
find /path/to/photos \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.png' \) -type f -exec mv -nv -t '/path/to/master' -- {} +
```

If you don't want to filter by extension, and just move everything (i.e., all the *files*):

```
find /path/to/photos -type f -exec mv -nv -t '/path/to/master' -- {} +
```

The `-n` option so as to not overwrite existing files (optional if you don't care) and `-v` option so that `mv` shows what it's doing (very optional).

The `-t` option to `mv` is to specify the target directory, so that we can stack all the files to be moved at the end of the command (see the `+` delimiter of `-exec`). If your `mv` doesn't support `-t`:

```
find /path/to/photos \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.png' \) -type f -exec mv -nv -- {} '/path/to/master' \;
```

but this will be less efficient, as one instance of `mv` will be created for each file.

Btw, this *moves* the files, it doesn't *copy* them.

**Remarks.**

- The directory `/path/to/master` must already exist (it will not be created by this command).
- Make sure the directory `/path/to/master` *is not* in `/path/to/photos`. It would make the thing awkward!

Comment: Awesome! Does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `-execdir` option of `find`:

```
find /path/of/images -type f -execdir mv '{}' /master-dir \;
```

As per **`man find`**:

```
 -execdir utility [argument ...] ;
     The -execdir primary is identical to the -exec primary with the exception that 
     utility will be executed from the directory that holds the current
     file.  The filename substituted for the string ``{}'' is not qualified.
```

Since `-execdir` makes `find` execute given command from each directory therefore only base filename is moved without any parent path of the file.

Comment: I'm not sure the `execdir` is mandatory here... and I'm not even sure this does exactly whaty you want (it will also move subdirectories). This is a really messy command `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Please test it out.

Comment: Check the difference between `find . -execdir echo '{}' \;` and `find . -exec echo '{}' \;` outputs and you will realize how `-execdir` is handy here.

Comment: `mkdir -pv anubhava/subdir{1,2}/subsubdir{1,2} master; touch anubhava/subdir{1,2}/subsubdir{1,2}/file; find anubhava -execdir mv {} master \;` Oh dear it doesn't work as expected!

Comment: Don't worry about me, I know exactly what `-execdir` does `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: You can very well see the difference between 2 commands I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: Have you _tried_ your command? `:)`. Once again, don't worry about me, I know what `-execdir` does. And I'm still claiming that `-execdir` is completely useless here.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I am not worried about you :) I didn't start commenting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40875/discussion-between-gniourf-gniourf-and-anubhava)

Comment: Your command just doesn't work, hence the downvote. I tried to explain to you but you won't listen.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Don't downvote with so much negativity in mind. Try this command from your created subdir/files and you will know what I am talking about: **`find $PWD/anubhava -type f -execdir mv '{}' $PWD/master/ \;`**

Comment: Ah you added `-type f`!!! you see that I was right when I said it didn't work? you have to edit your post so I can remove the downvote. (btw, the `-execdir` is useless, it would work as well with just `-exec`).

Comment: When you say: _Since `-execdir` makes `find` execute given command from each directory therefore only base filename is moved without any parent path of the file._ This is how `mv` works...

Comment: A lot of times. Yet, when someone says my answer doesn't work, I do listen to him! Now please edit your answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: I have already edited it by adding `- type f` and tested it again to make sure it works. Again I never said that this is the only way it will work, there are other ways to make it work also.

Answer (score 0):

```
find <base location of files> -type -f -name \*\.raw -exec mv {} master \;
```

Comment: Oh dear, this fails miserably if there are files with `.raw` extension in the current dir. Please use more quotes!

Comment: `'*.raw'` would be enough!

Comment: true. just a preference.

Answer (score 0):

If your hierachy is only one level deep, here is another way using the automated tools of [StringSolver](https://github.com/MikaelMayer/StringSolver):

```
mv -a firstfolder/firstfile.raw firstfile.raw
```

The `-a` options immediately applies the similar transformation to all similar files at a nesting level 1 (i.e. for all other subfolders).
If you do not trust the system, you can use other options such as `-e` to explain the transformation or `-t` to test it on all files.

DISCLAIMER: I am a co-author of this work for academic purposes, and working on a bash script renderer. But the system is already available for testing purposes.